# Can't show tk window

Tags: python, function, class, tkinter

I am new to Python so I tried to test some short script/program using Pyscripter editor 
but I can not make it work. There is no output.

```
from Tkinter import*
class Myclassx:
     def __init__(self):
        windx = Tk()
        btnx = Button(text="okayx",command =self.printx)
        btnx.pack()
     def printx(self):
        print "see you later"
oleyx=Myclassx()
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Could you please be more specific with "I can not make it work"? What error did you get?

Comment: Please use a more descriptive title, as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean you don't see the window, you missed `windx.mainloop()`.

```
from Tkinter import*
class Myclassx:
     def __init__(self):
        windx = Tk()
        btnx = Button(text="okayx",command =self.printx)
        btnx.pack()
        windx.mainloop() # <----
     def printx(self):
        print "see you later"

oleyx=Myclassx()
```

Comment: Thanks it worked now but it says"global name 'windx' is not defined"

Comment: @sabitgencoglu, That does not make sense. Can you post your code as is? (no, not as answer. edit your question with traceback as is)

Comment: The program is supposed to display "see you later" when the button pressed

Comment: @sabitgencoglu, That (displaying "see you later") also works. As I said in the previous comment, please post your code as is.

Comment: oh I see it now. ..well I was expecting it somewhere on the window(right below the button) I think I need a label or textbox to display it ..anyway how can I mark my post as "solved" ? and give some reputation to "falsetru"

Comment: @sbgencoglu, You did it :)

Comment: So how do I modify the code so it uses a label or textbox to display the message ?

Comment: @sbgencoglu, Post another question.